# Reactotron core client causing Jenkins build fail?

Tags: react-native, jenkins, reactotron

I do not have a lot of experience with Jenkins, could someone assist me in what to look for inside this error message regarding what failed about this build?

```
08:47:43 Started by upstream project "Build/Build Mac Component" build number 3703
08:47:43 originally caused by:
08:47:43  Started by upstream project "Build/Build Component" build number 8094
08:47:43  originally caused by:
08:47:43   Started by upstream project "ENGA/ENGAL" build number 1831
08:47:43   originally caused by:
08:47:43    Started by remote host 172.16.6.8
08:47:43 Running as buildbot, svc
08:47:43 Setting version to: ENGAL 3.6.2-bug.1+127 from upstream version
08:47:43 [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
08:47:43 Building remotely on Michelle (mac) in workspace /Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL
08:47:43 Running Prebuild steps
08:47:43 [EnvInject] - Injecting environment variables from a build step.
08:47:43 [EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties file path '/Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/gitversion.properties'
08:47:43 [EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
08:47:43 Success build fororg.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.EnvInjectBuilder@5f11578e
08:47:43 [EnvInject] - Executing scripts and injecting environment variables after the SCM step.
08:47:44 [EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
08:47:44 JUNIT_REPORT_PATH=testResults/
08:47:44 CI=true
08:47:44 
08:47:44 [EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
08:47:44 Set build name.
08:47:44 New build name is 'JS! ENGAL 3.6.2-bug.1+127'
08:47:44 [description-setter] Description set: #3155: JS! Engage Application - Mobile
08:47:44 Recording fingerprints
08:47:44 [ENGAL] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/8m/t1fsdc0d1szd7b4tsxt9b0z40000gn/T/jenkins4398796249639990897.sh
08:47:44 + npm install
08:48:10 
08:48:10 > NFIBEngage@3.6.2-ci.1 postinstall /Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL
08:48:10 > rm -f ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/__fixtures__/files/package.json
08:48:10 
08:48:12 npm WARN reactotron-redux@3.1.0 requires a peer of reactotron-core-client@^2.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
08:48:12 npm WARN reactotron-redux@3.1.0 requires a peer of redux@^4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
08:48:12 
08:48:12 moved 2 packages in 26.06s
08:48:12 + npm version --allow-same-version 3.6.2-bug.1 --git-tag-version false
08:48:12 v3.6.2-bug.1
08:48:12 + npm run build
08:48:13 
08:48:13 > NFIBEngage@3.6.2-bug.1 build /Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL
08:48:13 > nps build
08:48:13 
08:48:13 nps is executing `build` : nps android.build && nps ios.build && nps finish
08:48:14 nps is executing `android.build` : node node_modules/rimraf/bin.js dist/*.apk && babel-node scripts/android/build.js
08:48:16 ########################### Starting Android Builds ###########################
08:48:16 starting gradle assembleDevRelease with flag - versionName=3.6.2-1831 -PversionCode=1831
08:49:19 ############################ Android Builds Failed! ############################
08:49:19 { Error: Command failed: ENGAGE_ENDPOINT=dv APPCENTER_KEY=f743d50f-82fa-4b23-b602-2a318b875480 ENGAGE_VERSION=3.6.2-1831 APPCENTER_PLATFORM=android npm run setup && cd android && ./gradlew assembleDevRelease -PversionName=3.6.2-1831 -PversionCode=1831 && cd ..
08:49:19 
08:49:19 Unable to resolve module `reactotron-core-client` from `/Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/node_modules/reactotron-redux/dist/index.js`: Module does not exist in the module map
08:49:19 
08:49:19 This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
08:49:19 To resolve try the following:
08:49:19   1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
08:49:19   2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
08:49:19   3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
08:49:19 
08:49:19 
08:49:19 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
08:49:19 
08:49:19 * What went wrong:
08:49:19 Execution failed for task ':app:bundleDevReleaseJsAndAssets'.
08:49:19 > Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
08:49:19 
08:49:19 * Try:
08:49:19 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
08:49:19 
08:49:19 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
08:49:19 
08:49:19 BUILD FAILED in 52s
08:49:19 
08:49:19     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
08:49:19     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
08:49:19     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
08:49:19     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
08:49:19     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
08:49:19     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
08:49:19     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
08:49:19     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12)
08:49:19   killed: false,
08:49:19   code: 1,
08:49:19   signal: null,
08:49:19   cmd: 'ENGAGE_ENDPOINT=dv APPCENTER_KEY=f743d50f-82fa-4b23-b602-2a318b875480 ENGAGE_VERSION=3.6.2-1831 APPCENTER_PLATFORM=android npm run setup && cd android && ./gradlew assembleDevRelease -PversionName=3.6.2-1831 -PversionCode=1831 && cd ..' }
08:49:19 ============================= Copying APK to Dist =============================
08:49:20 nps is executing `ios.build` : node node_modules/rimraf/bin.js dist/*.ipa && babel-node scripts/ios/build.js
08:49:23 ############################# DEV Build IOS Start #############################
08:49:23 ENGAGE_ENDPOINT=dv APPCENTER_KEY=e53bdbfb-dbdd-4ab9-8b4c-9d391e602cfa ENGAGE_VERSION=3.6.2-1831 APPCENTER_PLATFORM=ios npm run setup && xcodebuild -workspace ios/NFIBEngage.xcworkspace -configuration Release -scheme DEV -derivedDataPath /Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/ios/build -archivePath /Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/ios/build/Archive/DEV.xcarchive archive -UseModernBuildSystem=NO && xcodebuild -archivePath /Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/ios/build/Archive/DEV.xcarchive -exportPath /Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/dist -exportOptionsPlist /Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/scripts/ios/dev.plist -exportArchive
08:54:39 ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
08:54:39 
08:54:39 
08:54:39 The following build commands failed:
08:54:39    PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DEV/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/NFIBEngage.build/Release-iphoneos/DEV.build/Script-6BE83F58202A54D500662052.sh
08:54:39 (1 failure)
08:54:39 child_process.js:526
08:54:39     throw err;
08:54:39     ^
08:54:39 
08:54:39 Error: Command failed: ENGAGE_ENDPOINT=dv APPCENTER_KEY=e53bdbfb-dbdd-4ab9-8b4c-9d391e602cfa ENGAGE_VERSION=3.6.2-1831 APPCENTER_PLATFORM=ios npm run setup && xcodebuild -workspace ios/NFIBEngage.xcworkspace -configuration Release -scheme DEV -derivedDataPath /Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/ios/build -archivePath /Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/ios/build/Archive/DEV.xcarchive archive -UseModernBuildSystem=NO && xcodebuild -archivePath /Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/ios/build/Archive/DEV.xcarchive -exportPath /Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/dist -exportOptionsPlist /Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/scripts/ios/dev.plist -exportArchive
08:54:39 ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
08:54:39 
08:54:39 
08:54:39 The following build commands failed:
08:54:39    PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/DEV/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/NFIBEngage.build/Release-iphoneos/DEV.build/Script-6BE83F58202A54D500662052.sh
08:54:39 (1 failure)
08:54:39 
08:54:39     at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:483:13)
08:54:39     at execSync (child_process.js:523:13)
08:54:39     at /Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/scripts/ios/build.js:155:5
08:54:39     at Array.forEach (native)
08:54:39     at run (/Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/scripts/ios/build.js:117:16)
08:54:39     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/scripts/ios/build.js:166:1)
08:54:39     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
08:54:39     at loader (/Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
08:54:39     at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
08:54:39     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
08:54:39 The script called "ios.build" which runs "node node_modules/rimraf/bin.js dist/*.ipa && babel-node scripts/ios/build.js" failed with exit code 1 https://github.com/kentcdodds/nps/blob/v5.7.1/other/ERRORS_AND_WARNINGS.md#failed-with-exit-code
08:54:39 The script called "build" which runs "nps android.build && nps ios.build && nps finish" failed with exit code 1 https://github.com/kentcdodds/nps/blob/v5.7.1/other/ERRORS_AND_WARNINGS.md#failed-with-exit-code
08:54:39 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
08:54:39 npm ERR! errno 1
08:54:39 npm ERR! NFIBEngage@3.6.2-bug.1 build: `nps build`
08:54:39 npm ERR! Exit status 1
08:54:39 npm ERR! 
08:54:39 npm ERR! Failed at the NFIBEngage@3.6.2-bug.1 build script.
08:54:39 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
08:54:39 
08:54:39 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
08:54:39 npm ERR!     /Users/nfib/.npm/_logs/2019-05-24T13_54_39_789Z-debug.log
08:54:39 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
08:54:39 Set build name.
08:54:39 New build name is 'JS! ENGAL 3.6.2-bug.1+127'
08:54:39 Variable with name 'BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME' already exists, current value: 'JS! ENGAL 3.6.2-bug.1+127', new value: 'JS! ENGAL 3.6.2-bug.1+127'
08:54:45 Archiving artifacts
08:54:48 Finished: FAILURE
```

It seems Jenkins is having a problem locating the `reactotron-core-client`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the line you're looking for.

```
Unable to resolve module `reactotron-core-client` from `/Users/nfib/Jenkins/Jenkins-Workspaces/ENGA/ENGAL/node_modules/reactotron-redux/dist/index.js`: Module does not exist in the module map
```

Looks like it's probably a dependency issue.  It also tells you it happens during this step:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleDevReleaseJsAndAssets'.
```

If you need to see exactly what the workspace looks like and you're running pipeline builds, you can use the following line right before the step that fails:

```
archiveArtifacts '**\\*.*'
```

If you're not using pipeline builds, you can find the step as "Archive the Artifacts" in the Post Build Actions.